# Predicting dates using dates

Tags: r, machine-learning, statistics

I want to create a simple model that I can use to predict future dates. All I want to use is a list of dates and use that to best predict the future dates. Here is what I've done so far:

```
sales_modified = data.frame(City=sales$City, SOCreatedOn=sales$SOCreatedOn)
sales_modified = sales_modified[order(sales_modified$City,sales_modified$SOCreatedOn),]
sales_modified = unique(sales_modified)
sales_modified$rowNum = 1:length(sales_modified$City)
ggplot(data = sales_modified[1:119,], aes(x=rowNum, y=SOCreatedOn)) + geom_point(aes(color=City)) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) + facet_wrap(~City)+ geom_smooth(method="lm")

date1 = lm(SOCreatedOn ~ rowNum, data = sales_modified[1:119,])
```

That formats the date and keeps it in a data frame called `sales_modified` which creates two columns, a City and a Date. The reason I created a `rowNum` column was to plot it somehow neatly and also to create the model. I tried using `lm()` to figure out the linear model. How can I find the next future dates without providing any additional data?

EDIT:
Experimenting with ARIMA model, but it leads to just picking dates right after each other (4/27, 4/28, 4/29) when I know this won't be the case.

```
timeseries = ts(sales_modified$SOCreatedOn[1:119])
plot.ts(timeseries)

auto.arima(timeseries)
timeseriesarima = arima(timeseries, order = c(2,1,0))
timeseriesforecast = forecast.Arima(timeseriesarima, h = 5)
as.Date(timeseriesforecast$mean[1:5])
```

Answer (score 0):

While I do share @Rob's concern about the time-series violation of independence, it's likely that only you can best assess this (whether one data point gives you information about the next).

That being said, it's pretty easy to predict new responses from an `lm` model if you're comfortable with its appropriateness.  Check out `?predict.lm`, and try something like

```
newdate <- predict(date1, newdata=data.frame(rowNum=120:140))
```

If you find that it's more appropriate to use an ARIMA model as @Rob suggested, check out `?predict.Arima`.  Usage will similarly look like `predict(yourARIMAmodel)`.

Comment: Okay I think I want to use an ARIMA model, but again from my understanding I need to create a vector that has data that depends on dates. In my case what would I use when trying to create a time series?

Comment: Actually I think I got it, could you check my edit and let me know if I am right?

Comment: Without knowing how your dataset works, I'm not really sure.  The code looks like it could be right, but if it gives results that don't make sense, then there's probably something still wrong.  Maybe migrate to Crossvalidated?

Answer (score -1):

Time series data violates the assumption that adjacent data point are independent of each other, a simple linear regression will not correctly account for this. Consider an ARIMA model  (?arima)

Comment: How could I use this if the dates itself is the variable I want to model?